# Why can I only use SourceGraphic as in2 in a feDeformationMap?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

If I use 'SourceGraphic' as `in2` inside `feDisplacementMap`, things looks good. However, if I use anything else, the deformation is not applied.

Because of that, I have to define the deformation source first, and then apply the filter to the deformation source, which is quite counter-intuitive, at least for me.

For example, in the example below I have to define the circle and then apply the filter to the circle. Inside the filter I use `feImage` to load the kitten image. But that feels reverse to me. This works:

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="displace">
      <feImage href="https://placekitten.com/500/500" result="kitten" />
      <feDisplacementMap
        scale="10"
        xChannelSelector="R"
        yChannelSelector="R"
        in="kitten"
        in2="SourceGraphic"
      />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="#f00" filter="url(#displace)" />
</svg>
```

As you can see, applying a displacement to a small part of an image becomes quite painful, as you have to first create the displacement map yourself, and it must have the same size as the image. Like this:

```html
<g id="deformation-source" filter="url(#displace)">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width={imageWidth} height={imageHeight} fill={neutralToDeformation} />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="#f00" filter="url(#displace)" />
</g>
```

Also, applying 2 different deformations to the same image, requires you to put the objects that will cause the deformation, instad of doing something like this:

```html
<image href="kitten-url" filter="url(#filter-1)" />
<image href="kitten-url" filter="url(#filter-2)" />
```

What I would like to be able to do is to load the kitten as an SVG `image` tag, and then apply the filter to that image, where I would load the circle inside a `feImage` making a reference to the object's id, which I would have previously defined inside the `defs` section. This doesn't work:

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <circle id="displacement-source" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="#f00" />
    <filter id="displace">
      <feImage href="displacement-source" result="displacement-source" />
      <feDisplacementMap
        scale="10"
        xChannelSelector="R"
        yChannelSelector="R"
        in="SourceGraphic"
        in2="displacement-source"
      />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <image href="https://placekitten.com/500/500" width="100" filter="url(#displace)" />
</svg>
```

I'm not sure if I'm the one that's thinking this backwards or if I'm missing something. What's going on with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can define your displacement source within the feImage, but it has to be an complete image defined as an inline URI in order to be cross browser compatible.

```
<feImage width="500" height="500" xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='247' height='34'etc. etc.
```

Please see [this article for more detail on how to escape characters in the svg+xml format](https://bl.ocks.org/jennyknuth/222825e315d45a738ed9d6e04c7a88d0#:%7E:text=%22So%20the%20best%20way%20of,because%20URLs%20are%20always%20ASCII.%22) - as far as I can remember there are some gotchas vs. vanilla HTML escaping.

If you don't care about Firefox, you can use a fragment identifier instead of inlining a whole SVG.

```
<feImage width="500" height="500" xlink:href="#idOfElementYouWantToUse"/>
```

Also remember that there are cross-origin security rules on displacementMap sources - so you can't displace an image using a map from another domain (or vice versa - I'm a little hazy on which way the restrictions run).